# Error while installing jruby on windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, jrubyonrails

I am trying to install JRuby in my system, I follow the following steps:

- Download a copy of the latest JRuby from the JRuby download page.
- Unzip the file with your achive program. If you don't have one that works, download 7-Zip.
- Copy the JRuby folder called jruby-1.7.2 directly to "C:/"
- Set environment variables on your system. Right click "My Computer" go to "Advanced" then "Environmental Variables". Create these: `JRUBY_HOME = C:/jruby-1.7.2`
- Next you'll have to edit the PATH variable. Add `;C:\jruby-1.1.5\bin;` to the end of that variable.

And then I am running the command:

```
C:\Users\sitanshu\rubyApp\jruby-1.7.2>jruby -v
```

then it shows the following error:

```
jruby 1.7.2 (1.9.3p327) 2013-01-04 302c706 on Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 1.7.0-ea-b19 [Windows Vista-x86]
NameError: uninitialized constant Java::JavaLang::ProcessBuilder::Redirect
   const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2677
  ProcessManager at file:/C:/Users/sitanshu/rubyApp/jruby-1.7.2/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel/jruby/process_manager.rb:12
           JRuby at file:/C:/Users/sitanshu/rubyApp/jruby-1.7.2/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel/jruby/process_manager.rb:6
          (root) at file:/C:/Users/sitanshu/rubyApp/jruby-1.7.2/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel/jruby/process_manager.rb:3
            load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1046
          (root) at file:/C:/Users/sitanshu/rubyApp/jruby-1.7.2/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/kernel.rb:1
```

So where am I going wrong and what is the solution for that?

Comment: define %JAVA_HOME% maybe

Comment: `Add ;C:\jruby-1.1.5\bin; to the end of that variable.` Is the `1.1.5` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

I would test that java is updated and working

```
java -version
```

Answer (score 0):

Under your environment variables, make sure you have a `JAVA_HOME` variable pointing to your JRE root folder, like this:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\`

Make sure your Java JRE bin folder is also part of your `PATH` variable:

- `;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\`

Additionally, when you are adding jruby to your `PATH` variable, make sure you are referencing the correct folder location.  In the example you have given, you are installing jruby to `C:\jruby-1.7.2`, but then you are actually referring to this different folder `C:\jruby-1.1.5` in your `PATH` configuration.

Also, when you are defining your JRUBY_HOME variable, make sure you are using backslash `\` characters.  In your example above you used a forward slash `/` character.  Remember, that windows uses backslashes between folders.

Finally, after you've made all your environment variable changes, remember to open a new command window for your changes to take effect.